# Topology closure

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. Let $A\subset X$

My professor defined the closure of $A$ as the set of points in $X$ so that $\forall$ $U$(open) containing $x$, $U \cap A$ is non-empty.

The question I have is which of the following ones are logically equivalent to the one the Professor gave?

$\forall$ $U$(open) containing $x$, $U \cap A$ is non-empty.

(1) $\forall U$ ($ U \in \tau$ and $ x\in U \implies U \cap A $ is not empty)?

Or

(2) $\forall U$ ($ U \in \tau$ and $ x\in U \textbf{ and } U \cap A $ is not empty)?

Or

(3) $\forall U$ ($ U \in \tau$ $\implies$ $ x\in U \textbf{ and } U \cap A $ is not empty)?

Please explain why.

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy why can’t it be: $\forall U$ $( U \in \tau$ and $ x\in U \textbf{and} U \cap A $ is not empty)$ ?

Comment: @topologicalmagician Because that would assert that, for every (not necessarily open) subset of $X$, that $U \in \tau$ (i.e. every subset is open) and $x \in U$ (every subset contains $x$) and $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ (every subset intersects $A$). This is never true, as it doesn't exclude $U = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 1 is correct: when we quantify over all open sets (or equivalently over all $U \in \tau$)) we know the implication **if** $x \in U$ **then** $U$ must intersect $A$. We do not know that all open sets contain $x$; this will be exceedingly rare or even false as $\emptyset$ is open in any $X$..

So correct is

$$\forall U \in \tau: (x \in U \implies U \cap A \neq \emptyset)$$

Answer (score 0):

1 is correct.

2 implies that all open open sets contain $x$.
That is false.  For example $\Bbb R - \{x\}$ is open and excludes $x$.

3 implies that if $U$ is an open set, then $x \in U$
which again is false.  $U=\emptyset$, for example.